# Return all the records not before 2 hours which is going to be expired from the booked date and time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have show a flag if the expire date and time is there within 2 hours from the booked date and time.

I am saving date and time in two different columns like

```
date              time
2017-11-08       18:20
2017-11-09       21:20
2017-11-09       17:20
2017-11-10       22:20
```

Current time is 19:00

```
 I want to get 2017-11-09 21:20 and 2017-11-10 22:20
```

I have tried the query like this

```
CASE 
    WHEN ADDTIME(ts.schedule_date, twp.arrival_time) > SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND 
    ADDTIME(ts.schedule_date, twp.arrival_time) >= NOW()  THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) schedule_status
```

Here i'm getting 1 hour difference records only.

Comment: Could you post some desired output, 'cause is not really clear what you want

Comment: I want to get 2017-11-09 21:20 and 2017-11-10 22:20 because i have to get the results having time interval greater than 2 hours

Comment: can you clarify what you are looking for? for the data you give, an interval of 2 hours from 19:00 will give the same result as 1 hour interval, i.e. 18:20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example here of how you can do it: http://rextester.com/DQT4773

Here is the query:

```
select
    date
    ,time
    ,case when
       concat(date,' ',time) > DATE_ADD('2017-11-09 19:00', INTERVAL 2 HOUR) then 1 else 0 
    end as flag
from <your_table>;
```

Just change the hard-coded date-time to `NOW()`; I wrote it like this based on your example